# A progress bar or seek bar just like samsung health

Tags: android

Can someone tell me how can I draw a progress bar or seek bar just like Samsung health? Sample is provided below.[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help you :

https://uxplanet.org/top-15-seekbar-and-slider-github-ui-libraries-and-components-java-swift-kotlin-d0f6a9658be3

Comment: Seen it before. Actually what I was is the images of users in a step count challenge

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom Range seekbar for that and you can find many more in github below i have give few links please refer that
1)
[Click here for custom Range Seekbar example 1](https://github.com/Jay-Goo/RangeSeekBar)

2)[Click here for custom Range Seekbar example 2](https://github.com/nickwinder/range-bar-preference)

Comment: Yes, it was helpful but I need to add the user's image on seek bar. I don't know how to do that.